# How do I get escape characters to work for new lines in the MS Word API?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I'm not sure why the escape characters won't create new lines?

```
MSWord ITSM = new MSWord("C:/users/o519731/Desktop/ITSM.docx");

XWPFParagraph copyITSM = ITSM.Document.createParagraph();
XWPFRun enterText = copyITSM.createRun();

enterText.setText("First line.\n");
enterText.setText("Second line.\n");
enterText.setText("Third line.");

ITSM.Document.write(ITSM.wordStream);
ITSM.wordStream.close();
System.out.println("Document Created.");
```

Results in:

`First Line.Second line.Third line.`

Expecting each on a separate line:

`First line.
Second line.
Third line.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your systems defined newline escape character(s) for newlines.
Also escape double quotes if you wish them to appear in the file by adding a \ in front of them.

```
String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
enterText.setText("\"First line.\"");
enterText.addBreak();
enterText.setText("\"Second line.\"");
enterText.addBreak();
enterText.setText("\"Third line.\"");
enterText.addBreak();
```

Comment: Hi Michael! Sorry, that didn't seem to work. Still returns single line:

First line.Second line.Thrid line.

Comment: check my edit, how does that work? Do the quotes show up at all?

Comment: Hi Michael! That worked and I credited as such :)  However, I'm curious why I cannot get the escape characters to work? Thanks!

Comment: blame microsoft, they probaly use some internal markup language, instead of generics. So I suggest you learn the ins and outs of that markup language and how to escape, parse/show special characters.

Answer (score 0):

please escape the quote like

```
 enterText.setText("\"First line.\n\"");
    enterText.setText("\"Second line.\n\"");
    enterText.setText("\"Third line.\"");
```

Comment: Sorry, I added the quotes to show they were strings. I don't need the quotes, I just need them on separate lines an using "\n" or "\r" won't do it. Any thoughts as to why?